# Unable to get a:active to work on menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I have been struggling to get the active styling to work in my CSS file. I have looked at previous website I have designed which use it and cannot see what I am doing wrong in my current website. I would like the menu to change the text on the page currently being viewed to #FFFFFF. Depsite repeated attempts I have had no success.

The HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">

<header>
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="Images/Logo.jpg" alt="The Restaurant"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="food.html">FOOD</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">WINE</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">RESERVATIONS</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">GIFT VOUCHERS</a></li> 
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

The CSS:

```
        /* ===========================
       ======= CSS Reset ========= 
   =========================== */
    html, body, div, form, fieldset, img, legend, label, li, nav, ul{margin: 0; padding:     0;}
table{border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;}
th, td{text-align: left; vertical-align: top;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, th, td, caption {font-weight:normal;}
img {border: 0;}
p, h2{margin: 0;}

/* ===========================
   ======= Body style ======== 
   =========================== */
    html{
    background-color: #333333;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

.wrapper{

}

/* ===========================
   ======= Anchor style ====== 
   =========================== */
a {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #999999;
}

a img {
    border: 0px; 
    text-decoration: none;}


 /* ===========================
    ========= Header ========== 
    =========================== */
header{
    background-color: #2B2B2B;
    min-width: 100%; 
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    float: left;  
    height: 90px; 
}

.logo{
    background-color: #333333;
    height: 60px; 
    padding-left: 150px;    
}

/* ===========================
   ===== Main Navigation ===== 
   =========================== */
.menu{
    background-color: #333333;
}
.menu nav{
    float: left; 
    padding-left: 150px; 
    padding-bottom: 8px; 
    padding-top: 8px;   
}
.menu nav ul{
    list-style: none; 
}
.menu nav ul li{
    display: inline;     
    padding-right: 15px; 
}
.menu nav ul li a{
    padding-top: 5px; 
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.menu nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/B9VLP/)

add a class `.current` to your css and html:

```
.current {
    color:white;
}

<li><a class="current" href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
```

This will work as long as the html for the menu is on every page.  If you use 1 menu in an html file that is called into every page via something like `<!--#include file="includes/menu.html" -->` then you would need to use a bit of javascript on each page to add the `.current` class to the `li` for the page being viewed

Comment: Thanks. It has been a while since I have used HTML and CSS so completely forgot this is the way I have previously done it. Gave it a go and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The :active selector is used to select and style the active link.

A link becomes active when you click on it.

It's working look here

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/6LxeL/)

```
a:active
{ 
background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand what the use of the `:active` pseudo class is for.

It is used to give feedback when a user actively selects something.  For example, if you had css `a:active { color: #fff; }`, when a user clicked on a link, the color of the link would turn white until the user released the mouse button.

What is seems like your trying to do is something you would do with javascript or the page when it is rendered by the server.

Using javascript, you would respond to what the user clicked on.  For example:

```
document.querySelectorAll('nav li').addEventListener('click', function(){
   //Add class or style to show the item is selected and remove from other nav items 
});
```

If a server is rendering it, you can easily have the server add a class or style to the nav item for the page it is rendering.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I completely misunderstood the pupose of the active pseudo class. Your explanation of the color changing until the user releases the mouse buttons definately clears things up for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen notes that :active needs to come after :hover to be effective.

Try

```
a:hover,a:active
{
/* stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use :focus in stead of :active.
Like mentioned above :active is on click

Answer (score 0):

`a:active` only changes the color when you click on the link wenn you release your mouse it changes back, to change the color on the selected site you need to add a class of `"active"` or something like this and style it.